# axios.post(): Upload doc encoded "base64" to File Service, still encoded after upload

Tags: post, file-upload, axios, base64

**Problem:**

Using method `axios.post()`, successfully **upload encoded document contents as 'base64'** to a remote File Manager. However, the **uploaded document is still encoded as 'base64'** in the remote File Manager.

Could you tell me what is typically required when submitting a method `axios.post()` request to **ensure decoding 'base64' bytes to a properly formatted document** during upload by remote service??

**Code:**

The following Typescript code using `axios.post()`, uploading in FormData file using **'base64'** bytes read from TXT file.

```
const filePath = './files/test.txt';
const fileName = Path.parse(filePath).name;
const fileExt = Path.parse(filePath).ext.replace('.', '');
const fileBytes = fs.readFileSync(filePath, { encoding: 'base64' });
const fileContentType = mime.lookup(fileExt) as string;

const folderPathDest = 'TEST';
const fileNameDest = `${fileName}.${fileExt}`;
const filePathDest = Path.join(folderPathDest, fileNameDest)

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileBytes, {
  contentType: fileContentType,
  filename: filePathDest,
});
formData.append('folderPath', folderPathDest);
formData.append('fileName', fileNameDest);

const config = {
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${hubspotToken}`,
    'Content-Encoding': 'base64' // ???
  },
};

const response = await axios.post('https://api.hubapi.com/files/v3/files', formData, config);
```

Comment: Why encode anything with base64? You're using `FormData` so why not simply attach the file for upload. See https://github.com/form-data/form-data#axios